# Python: String to function name, how does it work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In pandas you can get unique values of a column in a dataframe by

```
#List unique values in the df['name'] column
df.name.unique()
```

How does Python convert a function name to a string argument 'name'?

Comment: It's not a function name, it's an object property.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this.  Are you asking about pandas in particular?

Comment: @Barmar what makes you think it's a property?  Properties are implemented with descriptors: if it were a property, then `DataFrame.name` would resolve.

Comment: @wim My point was that it's used like a property, not a function, it's not `df.name()`.

Comment: Ah, then the correct term to use would be "attribute" in this context.  Properties have a specific meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataframes override [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) to hook into attribute resolution.  This allows returning arbitrary objects from `df.anything`.  The instance maintains an internal list of "real" attribute names in `self._internal_names_set` and a list of column names in `self._info_axis`.

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    """After regular attribute access, try looking up the name
    This allows simpler access to columns for interactive use.
    """

    # Note: obj.x will always call obj.__getattribute__('x') prior to
    # calling obj.__getattr__('x').

    if (name in self._internal_names_set or name in self._metadata or
            name in self._accessors):
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
    else:
        if name in self._info_axis:
            return self[name]
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

Source is [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f4c9d966fb20d9ca3221d31bd9eb31117065808c/pandas/core/generic.py#L4032).

Comment: Thanks, wim. You mentioned in comments that there are multiple ways of doing it. What are the other ways to do it? I am asking for any python class and not specific to pandas.

Comment: There is also [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__), which has first dibs but can be tricky to implement correctly.  However, the much more common and popular way to "own the dot" in attribute access is by using descriptors.  Read up on the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) in the docs.